# Javascript, function inside function problem

Tags: javascript, function

Hey, I was working with a javascript project and reached a problem that I just don't understand. Here is the code, it's not the one that I use in my project, but it's a simplified version.

```
var x;

function FetchBox() {alert("Worked");}

function A(m,n) { 
    x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange=function(){
        n(); 
        x.send();
    };
}

A("http://jsfiddle/echo/xml/", FetchBox);
```

I can easily change the function to make it work:

```
function A(m,n) { 
    x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange=n();x.send();
}
```

But in my more complex version I want to add a readyState function and a few other things.

```
function A(m,n) { 
    x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange=
        if(x.readyState===4){
            n(); 
            x.send();
        };
}
```

Why can't I include a function inside this function? JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/M6Upv/17/

Have a good weekend,
Ulrik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try that way.

```
function A(m,n) { 
    x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(x.readyState===4) {
            n(); 
            //x.send(); //look below
        };
    }
    x.send() //I think, it should be here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing when you change it is simply calling `n()`, assigning its return value to `x.onreadystatechange` and then calling `x.send()`. Wrapping your code in `function() { .. }` delays the computation to when the callback is actually triggered. You'd still need to wrap your code in `function() { .. }` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't clear what you are trying to do, but here are some things you are doing wrong:

`onreadystate` should be a function that gets called whenever the readystate changes.

In your last example, you are trying to assign an if statement to it, which makes no sense at all.

In previous versions you are calling `send()` inside it — which makes no sense, as it isn't going to start firing until after `send()` has been called.

In all versions, you are defining `x` as a global, which is a good way to trigger race conditions.

Comment: Dorward: I apologise that I didn't explain my intentions with the function properly. You were right about the send(), but doesn't the `var x;` make sure `x` is local? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Unless there is a function around all that code, not really. It makes it local to the outermost environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `x.send()` before the `x.onreadystatechange()` can be called.

```
function A(m, n) {
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4) {
            n();
        }
    };
    x.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `send()` to *outside* of the `onreadystatechange` event handler:

```
function A(m,n) { 
    x = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    x.open("GET", m, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(x.readyState === 4) {
            n(); 
        };
    }
    x.send();
}
```